# tkinter page not disappeared, destroy() not working

Tags: python, tkinter

i am using tkinter for python gui app development.

i want to disappear a page when user will sweep to new page.
i am just open a new object of new class, and want to disappear it by destroy() but destroy not works

code -

```
import reg as r
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Tech Eye", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self.parent, text="Admin Registration", command=self.reg).place(x=260, y=300)
        self.button3 = Button(self.parent, text="Exit", command=self.destroy).place(x=220, y=350) 
#this destroy also not working

    def reg(self):
        new = tk.Tk()
        new.geometry("600x600")
        new.title("Third Eye")
        self.destroy()
        st = r.Registration(new) 
#r is the another python file what i imported and Registration is the class
        st.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x600")
    root.title("Third Eye")
    run = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

what i can do now?

Comment: You don't need to create new `Tk()` instance, just use `root` for `Registration` class.

Comment: destroy not working not it's look so odd

Comment: please see this https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FsjYckgmlyxeY3rljmKZSrhJ8pl36gj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Then try `self.parent.destroy()` instead of `self.destroy()`.